# Python: Reusing Objects

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and am having trouble with reusing an object creation method but still creating new objects in the graphics module specifically. Like this:

```
no = 0
while 1 == 1:
     "win" + str(no) = GraphWin("...",10,10)
     no = no + 1
```

I know this doesn't work (and is useless) but how would you go about doing this without it breaking? It's so I could do something like this later:

```
c = 0
while c != int(n + 1):
     "win" + str(c).close()
     c = c + 1
```

So how would you integrate the no variable each time a new win is defined so that they could be distinguished later?

Andrew's answer worked ^^ thanks for the quick response!

Comment: `while 1 == 1`? Why not just `while True:`?? Anyways, that made me smile. :) Anyways, a couple questions: is your variable `n` already an integer? Strings do not have `close` methods; what are you trying to do there? How many `win`s are you making? Do they hold values? Is each window being assigned a number?

Comment: Oh neat well the more ya know :P Well each time through the loop it's supposed to create a new one, 1st loop: win0 = (...) 2nd win1 = (...) 3rd win2 = (...) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create an array of windows. What you would want to do is append each window you create to a given array, allowing you to close them later.

Here is an example:

```
windows = []
while Somecondition:
    windows.append(GraphWin("...",10,10))
```

and later:

```
for w in windows:
    w.close()
```

this being said, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do :). You are not insulting us by learning; quite the opposite actually.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a perfect match for a dictionary! Each one can have it's own independent value, along with it's separate window:

```
dictionary = {
    "1": GraphWin(Whatever parameters)
}
```

To access each individual one, just index:

```
dictionary["1"].close() # Gets you the value (GraphWin stuff) and let's you do anything
```

It allows you to distinguish and do things on them. To get all the values, just use the `iterkeys()` or `itervalues()` methods, to get every key or value. Hope it helps!